# Windows Mobile with Sql Compact CE on Win8 x64

Tags: windows-mobile, sql-server-ce

I have a Windows Mobile 5 project in Visual Studio 2005.
This still works fine on the mobile devices and windows XP 32-bit.
But now it needs to run on a windows 8 (64 bit).

The project uses System.Data.SqlServerCe 3.0.3600.0

Is it possible to run this on a recent windows version or is this not supported?

**Update:** This is the error when running directly from VS2005 without emulator:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'System.Data.SqlServerCe, Version=9.0.242.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' or one of its dependencies.
```

Comment: Have you tried compling for x86 and running it?

Comment: I can't choose x86. There are not platforms to choose from.

Comment: Oh yes there is... But they may be well hidden in VS 2005 http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms185328(v=vs.80).aspx - or are you executing the Windows Mobile project directly on your desktop?? I dont think that is possible.

Comment: Yes, I run it directly on the desktop. Without the emulator. This works fine if I don't use the Sql Server CE.

Comment: Do you have the 3.1 runtime installed on the desktop PC? http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17439 and force x86 on the .exe? http://erikej.blogspot.dk/2008/01/x64-and-sql-compact.html

Comment: Thanks, did worked for me: corflags prog.exe /32BIT+

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to force x86 on the .exe? With corflags prog.exe /32BIT+

http://erikej.blogspot.dk/2008/01/x64-and-sql-compact.html